# Android - Parsing config.xml to Map

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to parse all entries in my app config.xml to `Map<String,String>`
can't seem to find an easy way to do it..

The file is located in res/values/config.xml

Is there a way to get all keys identifiers with `mAppContext.getResources()` ?

Comment: What is `config.xml`, specifically? Is it an XML resource in `res/xml/` or something?

Comment: the one in res/values/config.xml

Comment: I am not aware of a standard `res/values/config.xml` file, at least in conventional Android app development. You may wish to edit your question to post what you have in your `res/values/config.xml` file, so we can advise you on how to consume it. Or, if this is tied to some specific framework (e.g., Cordova), update the tags in your question to reflect that framework.

Comment: for the sake of the question, if it was on res/xml - what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an arbitrary XML file in `res/xml/` or a related resource set (e.g., `res/xml-es/`), you would use `getXml()` on a `Resources` object to get an `XmlResourceParser`. By and large, this is just an `XmlPullParser` that knows how to read from a resource.

From there, you use the `XmlPullParser` event-based pull API to read in the XML.

For example, suppose we have `res/xml/words.xml` with the following:

```
<words>
  <word value="lorem" />
  <word value="ipsum" />
  <word value="dolor" />
  <word value="sit" />
  <word value="amet" />
  <word value="consectetuer" />
  <word value="adipiscing" />
  <word value="elit" />
  <word value="morbi" />
  <word value="vel" />
  <word value="ligula" />
  <word value="vitae" />
  <word value="arcu" />
  <word value="aliquet" />
  <word value="mollis" />
  <word value="etiam" />
  <word value="vel" />
  <word value="erat" />
  <word value="placerat" />
  <word value="ante" />
  <word value="porttitor" />
  <word value="sodales" />
  <word value="pellentesque" />
  <word value="augue" />
  <word value="purus" />
</words>
```

Then this code will populate an `ArrayList<String>` (named `items`) with the words:

```
  XmlPullParser xpp=getResources().getXml(R.xml.words);

  while (xpp.getEventType()!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (xpp.getEventType()==XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
      if (xpp.getName().equals("word")) {
        items.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
      }
    }

    xpp.next();
  }
```

You would need to tweak this for your XML structure (I do not know whether your "keys" are element names, specific attribute values, or what) and for your in-memory data representation (e.g., `mapStuff.put(xpp.getName(), xpp.getAttributeValue(0))`).

It is entirely possible that there are simpler solutions for whatever problem you are trying to solve with a `res/xml/config.xml` file. However, since we do not know what this file contains or how you are using the values contained in it, it would be difficult to advise you on alternative ways of packaging that data in your app.